# Configure Qt Creator to use Clang with Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt, gcc, android-ndk, qt5

It seems that `GCC` is now deprecated and [will be removed from the Android NDK](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/CHANGELOG.md); `Clang` will be used instead. That being said `Android NDK` will never have support for `GCC 5` and no updates will be made in regards to `GCC`.

That being said I wanted to use `Qt for Android` with `Clang` and it seems work has been done in this direction for `Qt 5.7.1`: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50724 but I don't know how to configure `Qt Creator` to use `Clang` for the `Android` configuration and `Qt Creator` doesn't autodetect the configuration:

[image]

Does anyone know how to configure `Qt Creator` and where the `Clang` compilers for `Android` are? It seems that they are somewhere in `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/` but I just can't seem to get it right. I use `Qt Creator 4.2.2`.

Is it possible to use `Qt for Android` with `Clang`?

Comment: Hi Jacob, did you resolve this?

Comment: @AndrewVovk Unfortunately not and we will really need to find a solution for this in the near future as we're developing products using Qt for Android and there is more and more need for it...it's sad Google dropped support for GCC...

Answer (score 3):

I have had some success with manually adding C and C++ clang compilers.

Compiler path: `/home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++`

Platform codegen flags: `-target armv7-none-linux-androideabi`

You will need Qt built the same way! My configure command is:

```
export OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/home/david/QtAndroidBuild/OpenSSL/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib -lssl -lcrypto'
./configure -xplatform android-clang \
    --disable-rpath \
    -nomake tests \
    -nomake examples \
    -android-ndk /home/david/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle \
    -android-sdk /home/david/Android/Sdk \
    -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 \
    -android-toolchain-version 4.9 \
    -android-arch armeabi-v7a \
    -android-ndk-platform android-19 \
    -skip qttranslations \
    -skip qtserialport \
    -skip qt3d  \
    -skip qtcharts \
    -skip qtdoc \
    -skip qtmultimedia \
    -openssl-linked \
    -no-warnings-are-errors \
    -opensource \
    -confirm-license  \
    -I /home/david/QtAndroidBuild/OpenSSL/libs/armeabi-v7a/include \
    -prefix /home/david/apps/QtAndroidClang \
    -recheck
```

You may not need/want OpenSSL so adjust as necessary. I Build 5.10.1.